# Parameter transfer for Class called within another Class

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop, design-patterns

My problem is that I have a `Class A` with some `Parameters` that I use in a few other Classes but during initializing one of these Classes I always have to set the parameters for `Class A` as well. I not know how to solve these redundancies. Let me give you an example.

I have a big dataset that I reduce, using some calculations to one column depending on some input parameter

```
Class ColumnCreator
    Sub New(a,b,c,d)
```

This `ColumnCreater` is a Class I use in different other Classes. E.g. for a special Report:

```
Class SpecialReport
    Sub New(e,f,g,a,b,c)

    Sub Create_Columns()
        dim myColumn = ColumnCreator(a,b,c)
```

I created a `GUI` so a User can create his own report depending on the arguments he sets. BUT I always have to set the `Parameters a,b,c` that I need for the `Create_Columns Class` in the Constructor of the Class that uses these Class as you can see in the constructor of `SpecialReport New(...,a,b,c)`. This must be a problem many programmers are facing and I do not know how to handel this. My first Idea was to write some kind of `Parameter Container Class`.

```
Class ParContainer
    Sub(a,b,c)
```

But this does not make the code better at all. I hope I made myself clear. Any ideas how to solve this? C# code is ok too.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have a Class SpecialReports with 6 Parameters in the Constructor and Class ColumnCreator with 8 Parameters in the Constructor. If I want to use the ColumnCreator in SpecialReports I have now 14 parameters in the construcotr.

Comment: Instead of passing in `a`, `b` and `c`, pass in a `ColumnCreator` object.  That way, you can just create one and then use it every time instead of creating a new one each time.